# Filter Multimap By Key Based on Date Range

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, multimap

I've got a data set containing payment transactions consisting of dates and amounts.   I'm storing these in a map data structure with the date as the key and amount as value.

Since there may be multiple payments per date, I'm using Multimap from the Google Guava library.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

Multimap<LocalDate,BigDecimal> payments = ArrayListMultimap.create();

payments.put(LocalDate.parse("12/25/2016",formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
payments.put(LocalDate.parse("01/15/2017",formatter), new BigDecimal("250"));
payments.put(LocalDate.parse("01/25/2017",formatter), new BigDecimal("500"));
payments.put(LocalDate.parse("03/20/2017",formatter), new BigDecimal("500"));
payments.put(LocalDate.parse("04/15/2017",formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
payments.put(LocalDate.parse("06/15/2017",formatter), new BigDecimal("1000"));
```

What's the recommended approach to filtering this map based on a date range?

For example, show the entries between 3/2/2017-3/31/2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Multimaps#filterKeys`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#filterKeys(com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) method allows you to filter an existing `Multimap` by keys matching any arbitrary [`Predicate`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) that you code.  Its return value is a `Multimap` that contains only the entries that satisfy the filtering predicate.

First, let's define a helper method that can create a `Predicate` for checking that dates are between a specified range.

```
private static Predicate<LocalDate> between(final LocalDate begin, final LocalDate end) {
    return new Predicate<LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(LocalDate date) {
            return (date.compareTo(begin) >= 0 && date.compareTo(end) <= 0);
        }
    };
}
```

After that, you can use the predicate to filter on your desired range.

```
void testFilterPayments() {
    Multimap<LocalDate, BigDecimal> payments = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2016-12-25"), new BigDecimal("1000"));
    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-15"), new BigDecimal("250"));
    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-15"), new BigDecimal("1250"));
    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-15"), new BigDecimal("2250"));
    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-25"), new BigDecimal("500"));
    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-03-20"), new BigDecimal("500"));
    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-04-15"), new BigDecimal("1000"));
    payments.put(LocalDate.parse("2017-06-15"), new BigDecimal("1000"));

    System.out.println(Multimaps.filterKeys(payments,
            between(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01"), LocalDate.parse("2017-04-01"))));
    // Output:
    // {2017-01-25=[500], 2017-03-20=[500], 2017-01-15=[250, 1250, 2250]}

    System.out.println(Multimaps.filterKeys(payments,
            between(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01"), LocalDate.parse("2017-01-15"))));
    // Output:
    // {2017-01-15=[250, 1250, 2250]}

    System.out.println(Multimaps.filterKeys(payments,
            between(LocalDate.parse("2016-01-01"), LocalDate.parse("2017-12-31"))));
    // Output:
    // {2017-06-15=[1000], 2017-01-25=[500], 2017-03-20=[500], 2016-12-25=[1000], 2017-01-15=[250, 1250, 2250], 2017-04-15=[1000]}

    System.out.println(Multimaps.filterKeys(payments,
            between(LocalDate.parse("2001-01-01"), LocalDate.parse("2015-12-31"))));
    // Output:
    // {}
}
```

I have simplified this example to use the default date format for parsing.  It appears your original sample uses a custom `formatter`, but all of the same techniques apply as far as filtering by a predicate.

My predicate implementation matches on an inclusive range for both `begin` and `end`.  If you had slightly different requirements (such as an exclusive range, such that `end` isn't included in the results), then you could adjust the implementation of `apply` accordingly.

Please be aware of some of the details noted in the JavaDocs for the `Multimap` instance returned by the `filterKeys` method, such as:

> The returned multimap is a live view of unfiltered; changes to one affect the other.
>
> ...
>
> The resulting multimap's views have iterators that don't support remove()...
>
> ...
>
> The returned multimap isn't threadsafe or serializable, even if unfiltered is.
>
> ...
>
> Many of the filtered multimap's methods, such as size(), iterate across every key/value mapping in the underlying multimap and determine which satisfy the filter. When a live view is not needed, it may be faster to copy the filtered multimap and use the copy.

As an added note, the `between` predicate can be made more flexible by changing the method signature to use generics that accept a variety of `Comparable` types, not just `LocalDate`.

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Predicate<T> between(final T begin, final T end) {
    return new Predicate<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(T value) {
            return (value.compareTo(begin) >= 0 && value.compareTo(end) <= 0);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `Multimap` to be sorted, otherwise you have to iterate it all. Fortunately, there's such a multimap:

```
ListMultimap<LocalDate, BigDecimal> multimap =
    MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();

... fill

// This cast is safe.
SortedMap<LocalDate, Collection<BigDecimal>> asMap =
    (SortedMap<LocalDate, Collection<BigDecimal>>) multimap.asMap();
SortedMap<LocalDate, Collection<BigDecimal>> subMap =
    asMap.subMap(from, to);
for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, Collection<BigDecimal>> e : subMap.entrySet()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: FWIW in this case both map views are [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html)s

Comment: @Xaerxess Right, thanks. Concerning `... some code` vs `// ... some code`: I do it in purpose. Neither version does anything useful as is. Mine doesn't even compile, but that's a good thing (you may miss a comment but you can't miss a compilation error). YMMV.

Comment: Fair enough, I reverted those comments. Fun fact: [Perl5 has `...` operator which dies with "Unimplemented" message](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#The-Ellipsis-Statement).